# JBoss Seam - Dealing with large data returned from SQL

Tags: sql, jboss, seam

I'm looking for techniques/best-practices to do deal with the way our web-based application works.

Currently when a user searches a field it can returns more than 10000 records at once which to me is a waste of bandwidth and memory.

Is there a way to limit the number of returned rows based on the numbers of rows selected  to display. i.e. if on the web page user selects 100 rows per page then only return the 100 rows instead of loading all 10000 at once , then when next-page is clicked the next 100 number of rows will be loaded and so on.

**UPDATE** : The current implementation fetches all the data, binds it to the `t:datatable` and `t:dataScroller` for navigation between the pages.

From my reading in JFS 1.1 there is no server-side pagination provided (Correct me if i'm wrong) and to provide such mechanism i need to write custom code such as http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/WorkingWithLargeTables

Can someone confirm is this is a good solution? Using RichFaces is not an option.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do server-side pagination using a jsf component, as an example in richfaces:

http://katzmaier.blogspot.com/2010/03/richfaces-server-side-pagination.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Current system uses JSF tags `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>` and `t:dataTable` so wouldn't it be better to use EntityManager? But Reading afew articles on how EntityManager is used to paginate result list it seems there is a lot that needs to be changed from BackBean class, to jsp to Navigation rules. IS there a book that covers this aspect of JBoss Seam (Pagination,dealing with large reuslt sets..). i don't feel i know enough to start making the changes.

Comment: No Navigation Rules here. You just need a JSF component that supports an external data source (just like the rich:dataTable). Unfortunately it seems that MyFaces doesn't support it. By the way Richfaces is one of the most supported JSF library by Seam.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a Paginator component to control the display of the relevant number of records?

If you need to restrict the number of rows returned this can be specified as part of your query syntax.

Comment: thanks for your reply, is that how its done generally? limiting rows by returning top 100 for example where large number of a data is need to be displayed.  believe it or not in our system the way its implemented is that if a given search criteria returns  100000 rows it then it would return the entire load which causes all sorts of memory issues with our tomcat.

Comment: I would put a limit on your query of, say, 200 rows, then display those rows in a Paginator component (e.g. the Richfaces one). Then as the user moves forward through the resultset you can summon more rows from the d/b as required.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the entityquery class. This one supports already server-side pagination and sorting. It works well with simple or richfaces datatables. Even jquery datatables on top of the plain jsf one is possible if you need some lightweight stuff.